# Facebook sharing from website in php

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I am trying to create custom share button in facebook ,But when click on facebook sharing button .it automatically scrap the content,not provided description and caption.I stuck from last two days ,please provide the steps of creating facebook App.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
   app_id=121959111687462
   &display=popup&amp;caption=An%20example%20caption 
   &link=https%3A%2F%2Ffoursomefinders.com%2F%2F
   &redirect_uri=https://foursomefinders.com/dashboard.php"target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

Comment: Facebook is removing the possibilities to set those values dynamically, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations Open Graph meta tags will be the only way to provide this information soon.

Comment: But in my one website ,I am doing that same ,that is up and runing.And when I share with the appid that works

Comment: It's a 90-day deprecation, so it **will stop working** roughly three month after API v2.9 was released (April 18th, 2017), even if you are still using a lower API version.

Comment: But I need to share the description,for events it is not static ,numbers of events are their.Please help me guys ,I am badly stuck.

Comment: Then you have to create a unique URL for each combination of title, description and thumbnail you want to share.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response,
I got dynamically value in while loop of (title ,description and image).If you have some snapshot then please provide me.

Comment: I got my solution ,their is a problem in URL.

Comment: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=411265979240506&display=popup&href=https%3A%2F%2Ffoursomefinders.com/eventdescription.php?id='.$id.'"%2F&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ffoursomefinders.com%2Feventdescription.php%2F?id='.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a>'; ?>

Comment: Note: when you want to share the website content in facebook ,you must put the problem URL,Because when you the page URL.The facebook directly scrap the image and description of the page ,you need to just the pass description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was mistake on my URL.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id='yourappid'&display=popup&href=https%3A%2F%2F'URL'/page?id=''"%2F&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FURL%2FURL%2F?id=''"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

Note: When you pass the URL.URL page is must contained the image and description.Please change the **appid** and **URL**.